# Fill a matrix with only pair values

Tags: r

I'm trying to fill a matrix of 12 rows and 15 cols with the pair values(2,4,6,8,...) sort by row.
I tried this command line:

```
x=c(2:2:360,nrow=12,ncol=15,byrow=TRUE)
```

But it gives me (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...)

For a matrix of two rows and 5 cols:

```
[2,    4,   6,   8,  10

 12,  14,  16,  18,  20]
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show expected result?

Comment: Here it is @PoGibas

Comment: You mean `matrix(seq(2, 360, by = 2), ncol = 15, byrow = TRUE)`?

Comment: Yes it is what I mean thank you! @Sotos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x=matrix(1:180*2, ncol = 15, byrow = TRUE)
```